# Does separating read/write operations improve program efficiency?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, file-io, data-structures

I've written a program for class which takes in data from a URL, parses it for key phrases and then writes to a text file the phrase, line number, and column number.

Currently I am doing this as a single operation where the URL is fed to a BufferedReader for reading, to a Scanner for Parsing and then into a loop where each line is combed through and a series of conditional statements are used to check for the presence of said key phrases. When a match is found I write to a file.

The file read is about 60K lines of text and it takes about 4000ms on average to run this full operation from start to finish. Would it be more efficient to break apart the tasks and first read through the file into a Data Structure and then output the results to the file instead of doing both at the same time?

Also, how big of an impact would pulling the data from the URL have vs. reading it locally? I have the option to do both and but figure this would depend upon my broadband speeds.

EDIT: Somewhat of a nice test case. Over the week we've changed our ISP and upgraded our broadband speeds from 6Mb/sec to 30Mb/sec. This is brought my average read/parse/write times down to 1500ms. Interesting to see how small variances can make such impacts in performance.

Comment: Profile your code. Find the bottleneck

Comment: the majority of the 4000ms is probably spent on the algorithm. so it doesn't really matter much what you do with network and file operations, as long as the algorithm cannot be optimized. Though, I would rather read in all data first to free network resources (so that they are not tied up by the lengthy parsing process). It probably won't matter much.

Comment: You should avoid reading entire files or URL contents into memory wherever possible. It doesn't scale and adds latency.

Comment: Yeah I was going to try a few different approaches to better understand what type of performance results I would get. Thought I'd reach out for some more experienced advice first though so I could better understand my findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the way you implement parallelism in your data crunching part.

At the moment you sequentially read everything - then crunch the data - then write it. So even if you broke it into 3 threads each one depends on the result of the previous.

So unless you start processing the data before it is fully received, this would not make a difference but only add overhead.

You would have to model a producer/consumer like flow where e.g. lines are read individually and then put on a work queue for processing. Same for processed lines which are then put on a queue to be written to a file.

This would allow parallel read / process / write actions to take place.

Btw - probably you are mostly limited by the speed to read the file from an URL, since all other steps happen locally and are orders of magnitudes faster.

Comment: Thanks for such a thought out response. Probably a trivial question here but this is new territory for me as my CS program is finally starting to delve into real theory. The assignment I was working on was just the first in the summer session and I'm assuming it will serve to spark debate and push the class forward.

Nevertheless. Previously I completed an AS in WebDev and fulfilled my Uni transfer requirements which looking back on it feel so mechanical vs. what I am tackling now. I imagine I will be getting more involved with SO as time goes on.